# how to print register value using rop (return oriented programming)?

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I've got an assignment to build rop code thats calls `printf` with the value inside `edx` register.

I'm stuck. I know the address of `printf` function, and I have a tools to find gadgets.

I'm trying to build a stack that looks something like:

> someROPCode, printf_address, ret_address, ropCodeThatWrite_EDX_Value (printf argument).

I tried: `someROPCode = add esp 0xc,re`t (jump over the `printf` func so I can write `edx` value on stack)

```
ret_address=doesn't matter
```

`ropCodeThatWrite_EDX_Value` = I thought about something like: `push eax`, `push edx` , `ret` (I can't using only `push edx` because I think it will cause infinite loop (I'm new at this) but now I'm stuck (it's pretty obvious that this is not the way).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

ROP is for bypassing non-executable stack. There are further security measures that need to be circumvented for a successful exploit. For this exercise let's focus strictly on ROP and assume you have a simple setup without ASLR and such. In particular we assume that you have easy access to the stack pointer and function addresses.

We'd like to invoke `printf("%d\n", edx)`. Using the normal 32 bit x86 cdecl calling convention we need those two arguments on the stack. The format string is easy, but we have to get `edx` into memory. Since we can't write any code we need to find existing instructions that do this for us. The C library is a good candidate. Spotting appropriate code is the hard part. Using `objdump` I have found the following promising snippet:

```
   2e535:       89 54 24 04             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
   2e539:       ff 55 14                call   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x14]
```

This puts `edx` on the stack in the right place and calls a function through a function pointer. Must be my lucky day, because said pointer is addressed using `ebp` and it's easy to set the value of that since the standard function epilogue frequently does `pop ebp; ret`. I found one such pair nearby, at offset `2e6C1`. Obviously the `call` will not return to our code, as such it will do undefined things after it has done the printing (it will most probably crash). If that bothers you, you'll have to find a more suitable code fragment. Don't forget to add the load address of the C library to the offsets you find.

Thus the required stack layout looks like this:

- `esp+00h`: address of `pop ebp; ret`
- `esp+04h`: `esp+00h` (address of address of `printf` offset by `-0x14`)
- `esp+08h`: address of code that puts `edx` on stack and calls function pointer
- `esp+0Ch`: `esp+18h` (address of format string)
- `esp+10h`: placeholder for `edx`
- `esp+14h`: address of `printf`
- `esp+18h`: format string `%d\n`

I hope this illustrates the idea well enough so that you can come up with a solution that fits your particular setup.